# Does using the KEEP option on SAS datasets improve read performance?

Tags: sas

Suppose I am trying to sum up one variable (call it `var_1`) in a very large dataset (nearly a terabyte).  The dataset is both long and wide.  My code would look like this:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=my_big_dataset SUM;
    VAR var_1;
RUN;
```

Would I get any performance gain at all by using the `KEEP` option on the dataset being read?  That is:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=my_big_dataset (KEEP=var_1) SUM;
    VAR var_1;
RUN;
```

In terms of disk I/O, I imagine that each record must be read in its entirety no matter what.  But perhaps less memory needs to be allocated to read the records.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does make a difference.  Most of the time it's not a large difference but if you start to have very wide or very long datasets you will start to see some benefit.

Search for `keep=` on the link below...

http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts298.html

If you're having performance issues then this may shave fractions of seconds or seconds off what you are doing but it's not going to cut your processing time in half.  Look for other optimization techniques if you need that.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of a datastep, all variables will be read into the PDV unless you specify a DROP or KEEP statement.

For procedures, I *expect* SAS is clever enough to only read any variables used within the procedure. Maybe someone can confirm this?

You could easily construct some tests to determine this.

Comment: Good suggestion - I will try to do some benchmarking in the course of the next few big reads from this set.

Answer (score 3):

I don't find anything indicating that the KEEP statement is more efficient (or necessary) for PROC MEANS.

You could, however, gain efficiency using a [WHERE](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/097-2010.pdf) statement as well as using other [OPTIONS](http://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2007/CodersCorner/COD_Elkin_WritingALean.pdf) within the MEANS code.

Answer (score 1):

I think a where statement is generally more efficient than a keep option.
**But** in this case, a where is useless, and I am not sure adding a keep option in the proc call will change something.

But you can test and check the process time in log.
Let us know!

Edit:

I had a test with one of the biggest dataset I have.
With a keep option I got: 0.03 process time
Without a keep option I got: 0.01 process time

So I guess SAS is already optimized for this case.